# How to Drag a Feature outside Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

In our application, we'd like to start a native (HTML) Drag&Drop operation from a marker/feature on the "CanvasMap" to the outside world (any HTML target that accepts that type of drag/drop operation).

Imagine we only 1 marker/feature on the CanvasMap. I would like **not** to drag it along the CanvasMap but drag it **outside** the CanvasMap: let's say I want to drop it in a DIV and I would like Openlayers to do that by starting a **native HTML Drag operation**.

How can I achieve this? Is there any way to configure Openlayers to allow this type of interaction with the outside (in this case through the HTML Drag and Drop manager) world?

Thank you very much. I believe this is a good feature for the product.

Comment: When you mention you want to drag and drop feature(s), do you mean, dragging the representation of the feature (the image) (could be useful for example for a puzzle) or get the textual representation of the feature (to share/export the feature(s) in other software)?

Comment: I want to drag, let's say Feature.get('data') (some data I stored in the Feature) using the native HTML drag and drop system since I want to drop that data into a custom-element/div outside the CanvasMap.

Comment: Imagine you have a map with 1000 features and the screen is splitted into 2 parts: **map** and **mail** (and this a special HTML component/list). I would like to use the native HTML drag and drop system to drag features (one by one) from the map into the mail component (that is internally representing dragged features as a List). Since we're using native HTML Drag and drop system, I'd also like to define what is stored within the Drag Event.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. I would prefer using an `ol.interaction.Select` to adress more or less the same requirements: when I select, I push the info from the feature into the other component. Not as nice as drag & drop but simpler. See a demo https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/4172a8202de3f56b013377acb8c576fb

Comment: I didn't find a good and performant way to solve this. I finally used a custom overlay (an Angular toolTip + decluttering component) I have to be the Drag initiator. Anyway, I still believe it could be a good feature for the product.

Answer (score 0):

set a click handler, when the user clicks on a feature set a div to the **native HTML Drag operation** that represents that feature